# How would i create a custom command for quantity control in mvvm form

Tags: xamarin, mvvm

I want to create a custom command control to handle the quantity control using an entry and 2 buttons

I have an mvvm page with the label and button showing in the viewmodel data template my buttons work they change the data pulled from the mysql database but it doesnt update the visual end of the quantity control(the entry).

```
 public class ProductDetailsViewModel : BaseProductDetailsViewModel
    {

        public string strOrderNumber3 = SigninPage.strOrderNumber;
        public string strEmail1 = SigninPage.strEmail;
        private string _productname;
        public string QuantityNew1 = string.Empty;

        private ICommand _quantityaddCommand;

        public ICommand QuantityAddCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_quantityaddCommand == null)
                {
                    _quantityaddCommand = new Command<ProductDetail>(async (productdetail) =>
                    {
                        await OnQuantityAddSelected(productdetail);
                    });
                }

                return _quantityaddCommand;
            }
        }



        private async Task OnQuantityAddSelected(ProductDetail productdetail)
        {
            productdetail.Quantity = (Convert.ToInt32(productdetail.QuantityOld) + Convert.ToInt32(1)).ToString();
            productdetail.QuantityOld = productdetail.Quantity;

            OnPropertyChanged(productdetail.QuantityOld);
            RefreshCanExcutes();
            
        }

        

        private ICommand _quantityminusCommand;

        public ICommand QuantityMinusCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_quantityminusCommand == null)
                {
                    _quantityminusCommand = new Command<ProductDetail>(async (productdetail) =>
                    {
                        await OnQuantityMinusSelected(productdetail);
                    });
                }

                return _quantityminusCommand;
            }
        }



        private async Task OnQuantityMinusSelected(ProductDetail productdetail)
        {
            if (productdetail.Quantity != "0")
            {


                productdetail.Quantity = (Convert.ToInt32(productdetail.QuantityOld) - Convert.ToInt32(1)).ToString();
                productdetail.QuantityOld = productdetail.Quantity;

                OnPropertyChanged("productdetail.QuantityOld");
                RefreshCanExcutes();

            }


        }


        private void RefreshCanExcutes()
        {
            (QuantityAddCommand as Command).ChangeCanExecute();
            (QuantityMinusCommand as Command).ChangeCanExecute();
            
        }

        public string ProductName
        {
            get { return _productname; }
            set { _productname = value; }
        }

        public ProductDetailsViewModel(string productparamter)
        {
            _productname = productparamter;
            
        }


        



        private ICommand _loadProductDetailsCommand;


        public ICommand LoadProductDetailsCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_loadProductDetailsCommand == null)
                {
                    _loadProductDetailsCommand = new Command(async () => await LoadProductDetails());
                }

                return _loadProductDetailsCommand;
            }
        }


        private List<ProductDetail> _productdetails;

        public List<ProductDetail> ProductDetails
        {
            get => _productdetails;
            set => SetProperty(ref _productdetails, value);
        }


        public async Task LoadProductDetails()
        {
            // Call the GetCategories method to load the categories from the database
            ProductDetails = await GetProductDetails();
        }

        // Method for downloading an image
        private async Task<byte[]> DownloadImageAsync(string url)
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                return await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
            }
        }

        // Method for getting the categories from the database
        private async Task<List<ProductDetail>> GetProductDetails()
        {
            // Initialize the list of categories
            List<ProductDetail> productdetails = new List<ProductDetail>();


            // Connect to the database
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("mysql string"))
            {
                connection.Open();

                // Create a command to select the categories from the database
                using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT name, productdetails, price, image, quantity FROM products WHERE name = '" + ProductName + "' ", connection))
                {
                    // Execute the command and read the results
                    using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            if (reader.FieldCount >= 5)
                            {
                                // Create a new category object
                                ProductDetail productdetail = new ProductDetail
                                {
                                    Name = reader.GetString(0),
                                    ProductDetails = reader.GetString(1),
                                    Price = "R " + reader.GetString(2),
                                    Price1 = reader.GetString(2),
                                    ImageUrl = reader.GetString(3),
                                    Quantity = reader.GetString(4),
                                    QuantityOld = reader.GetString(4),
                                    
                                };
                                
                                
                                // Download the image for the category
                                productdetail.ImageData = await DownloadImageAsync(productdetail.ImageUrl);

                                // Add the category to the list
                                productdetails.Add(productdetail);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            // Return the list of categories
            return productdetails;

        
        }
```

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App2.Views.ProductDetails"
             BackgroundImageSource="bckgrnd20Darken.jpg"
             >

    <StackLayout Padding="10">
        <Entry x:Name="txtQuantity" IsReadOnly="True" BindingContext="{Binding Quantity, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
        <Entry x:Name="txtQuantityOld" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <Label x:Name="txtOrderNumber"/>
        <CollectionView x:Name="productdetailsCollectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductDetails}" >
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="1" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="0" Padding="7" >
                        <Frame HasShadow="False" BorderColor="Black"  BackgroundColor="Transparent" CornerRadius="20">
                            <StackLayout Padding="5">
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" HeightRequest="200" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Title" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" Padding="10" />
                                <Label Text="About This Product" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10,10,10,10" TextColor="Black"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding ProductDetails}" Margin="10,10,10,10" FontSize="Large" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Price}" Margin="10,10,10,10" FontSize="Title" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Price1}" IsVisible="false"/>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Button
                                        x:Name="minusbutton"
                                        ImageSource="minus.png" 
                                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference productdetailsCollectionView}, Path=BindingContext.QuantityMinusCommand}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
                                    <Entry Text="{Binding Quantity}"/>
                                    <Entry Text="{Binding QuantityOld}"/>
                                    <Entry Text="{Binding QuantityNew, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                    <Button
                                        ImageSource="Plus.png"
                                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference productdetailsCollectionView}, Path=BindingContext.QuantityAddCommand}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <Button
                                    Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference productdetailsCollectionView}, Path=BindingContext.ProductDetailsCommand}" 
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                    Text="ADD TO CART"
                                    CornerRadius="20"
                                    BackgroundColor="Blue"
                                    TextColor="White"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
        
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

public class BaseProductDetailsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    //protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    //{
    //    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    //}

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
            return false;

        backingStore = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

        return true;
    }

    // Method for showing alerts
    protected async Task ShowAlert(string title, string message, string buttonText)
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(title, message, buttonText);
    }
}


public partial class ProductDetails : ContentPage
{
    public static string strOrderNumber1 = SigninPage.strOrderNumber;
    
    public ProductDetails(string ProductName)
    {
        
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = new ProductDetailsViewModel(ProductName);

        // Call the method to load the categories from the database
        ((ProductDetailsViewModel)BindingContext).LoadProductDetailsCommand.Execute(null);

        //txtQuantity.Text = strQuantity;
        //txtQuantityOld.Text = strQuantityOld;
        //txtQuantity.Text = txtQuantityOld.Text;
        //txtQuantity.Text = "0";
        //txtQuantityOld.Text = "0";
        
        txtOrderNumber.Text = strOrderNumber1;


        //strQuantity = txtQuantity.Text;
        //strQuantityOld = txtQuantityOld.Text;





    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please recheck if your model `ProductDetail` has implemented interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` .

From document [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-7.0),we could know that:

> The INotifyPropertyChanged interface is used to notify clients,
> typically binding clients, that a property value has changed.

Based on your code,I created a demo to achieve this function.

You can refer to the following code:

**ProductDetail.cs**

```
   public class ProductDetail: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public string ProductName{ get; set; }
    //public string Quantity { get; set; }

    private string _quantity;
    public string Quantity
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref _quantity, value); }
        get { return _quantity; }
    }

    // public string QuantityOld { get; set; }
    private string _quantityOld;
    public string QuantityOld
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref _quantityOld, value); }
        get { return _quantityOld; }
    }

    //public string QuantityNew { get; set; }
    private string _quantityNew;
    public string QuantityNew
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref _quantityNew, value); }
        get { return _quantityNew; }
    }


    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

**TestViewModel.cs**

```
public class TestViewModel 
    {

        public ObservableCollection<ProductDetail> Items { get; set; }

        public ICommand QuantityAddCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand QuantityMinusCommand { get; set; }

        public TestViewModel() {
            Items= new ObservableCollection<ProductDetail>();
            Items.Add(new ProductDetail {  ProductName="Product1", Quantity = "30", QuantityOld="10",QuantityNew="0" });
            Items.Add(new ProductDetail { ProductName = "Product1", Quantity = "40", QuantityOld = "10", QuantityNew = "0" });
            Items.Add(new ProductDetail { ProductName = "Product1", Quantity = "50", QuantityOld = "10", QuantityNew = "0" });

            QuantityAddCommand = new Command((object item) => {

                if (item != null && item is ProductDetail) {
                    ProductDetail productdetail = (ProductDetail)item;
                    productdetail.Quantity = (Convert.ToInt32(productdetail.QuantityOld) + Convert.ToInt32(1)).ToString();
                    productdetail.QuantityOld = productdetail.Quantity;
                
                }
            });

            QuantityMinusCommand = new Command((object item) => {
                if (item != null && item is ProductDetail)
                {

                    ProductDetail productdetail = (ProductDetail)item;

                    if (productdetail.Quantity != "0")
                    {
                        productdetail.Quantity = (Convert.ToInt32(productdetail.QuantityOld) - Convert.ToInt32(1)).ToString();
                        productdetail.QuantityOld = productdetail.Quantity;

                    }
                }
            });
        }


        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

Usage example:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:formcollectionviewapp="clr-namespace:FormCollectionViewApp"
             x:Class="FormCollectionViewApp.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <formcollectionviewapp:TestViewModel></formcollectionviewapp:TestViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <CollectionView  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="productdetailsCollectionView">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button    
                                        x:Name="minusbutton" Text="minus"
                                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference productdetailsCollectionView}, Path=BindingContext.QuantityMinusCommand}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
                    <Entry x:Name="txtQuantity" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Quantity}" />

                    <Entry x:Name="txtQuantityOld" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding QuantityOld}" />

                    <Entry Text="{Binding QuantityNew}"/>
                    <Button   Text="add"
                                        ImageSource="Plus.png"
                                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference productdetailsCollectionView}, Path=BindingContext.QuantityAddCommand}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>

                    <!--<Button Text="Remove"   Command="{Binding BindingContext.DeleteItemCommand, Source={x:Reference mCollectionView}}"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"  Margin="10,0,10,0" WidthRequest="80" HorizontalOptions="End"/>-->

                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>

</ContentPage>
```

**Note:**

At the same time, you can simplify your command code.

For example:

```
        public ICommand QuantityAddCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand QuantityMinusCommand { get; set; }
```

And initialize these two commands on the constructor of your viewmodel:

```
            QuantityAddCommand = new Command((object item) => {

                if (item != null && item is ProductDetail) {
                    ProductDetail productdetail = (ProductDetail)item;
                    productdetail.Quantity = (Convert.ToInt32(productdetail.QuantityOld) + Convert.ToInt32(1)).ToString();
                    productdetail.QuantityOld = productdetail.Quantity;
                
                }
            });

            QuantityMinusCommand = new Command((object item) => {
                if (item != null && item is ProductDetail)
                {

                    ProductDetail productdetail = (ProductDetail)item;

                    if (productdetail.Quantity != "0")
                    {
                        productdetail.Quantity = (Convert.ToInt32(productdetail.QuantityOld) - Convert.ToInt32(1)).ToString();
                        productdetail.QuantityOld = productdetail.Quantity;

                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

**Update:**

Since you have used MVVM for your app, why are you calling command  `LoadProductDetailsCommand` in page `ProductDetails.xmls.cs`?

```
((ProductDetailsViewModel)BindingContext).LoadProductDetailsCommand.Execute(null);
```

So, you can remove it:

```
    public partial class ProductDetails: ContentPage 
{
    public ProductDetails()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = new TestViewModel("test");

        // Call the method to load the categories from the database
        //((TestViewModel)BindingContext).LoadProductDetailsCommand.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

You can get data from database on the constructor of your viewmodel `ProductDetailsViewModel.cs`,just as follows:

```
  public  ProductDetailsViewModel(string productname)
    {

        //other code 

        _productname = productname;

        //load data from database here
        LoadProductDetails();
    }
```

Besides,I recommend that you define the type of `ProductDetails` as  `ObservableCollection<T>`:

```
    private ObservableCollection<ProductDetail> _productdetails;

    public ObservableCollection<ProductDetail> ProductDetails
    {
        get => _productdetails;
        set => SetProperty(ref _productdetails, value);
    }
```

In this case,once adding or removing item to `ProductDetails`,the UI will refresh itself.

Comment: I have my INotifyPropertyChanged in my baseviewmodel do you think i should remove it from there and put it in the viewmodel page?

Comment: This depends on your needs. If multiple subclasses share the properties of this base class, this base class is appropriate.

Comment: i tried the code you gave me and the page doesnt load in the content now im new to xamarin thats why i dont know too much on the finer details

Comment: `the page doesnt load in the content now`  Could you please post more code snippets so that we can test on our side?

Comment: I posted the full code for the page i just removed mysql string but everything else needed is there

Comment: `the page doesnt load in the content now`  Where exactly is it not loaded? Is the data not fetched, or is the data fetched but not displayed?

Comment: The data fetched from the mysql database isnt loading the page is showing up as blank when I modify my code with the code you provided

Comment: You mean you could get the data from the database, but the data couldn't display on the page,right?

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: Could you please post the full code of the latest `ProductDetailsViewModel.cs`  and the `YourPage.xaml`?

Comment: I haven't seen the other code of your app, and since you said that your previous code can display data, you can try just changing the code for `ProductDetail.cs`, just like my answer mentioned.

Comment: I just posted the needed code the productdetail.cs page is at the bottom of the BaseProductDetailsViewModel

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can check the updated part at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: the page is still showing up as blank could you give me new code on getting a quantity adder just a simple way to show plus and minus with the number inbetween the plus and minus and obviously increase when plus is clicked and decrease when minus is clicked

Comment: In the beginning,the code you required has been added to above answer . I couldn't see the latest whole code of your app, could you please post a basic demo to github and share the link here?

Comment: At first, you can debug to see if you can get the data from database with code :`public  ProductDetailsViewModel(string productname)
    {
        //other code 

        _productname = productname;

        //load data from database here
        LoadProductDetails();
    }`

Comment: I changed the code that you gave me and i got the page to load in and show the data but the button still doesnt do anything

Comment: You can take a closer look at the code of my initial answer and double-check yours. The code I uploaded works fine on my side.

Comment: https://github.com/SystemsUnlimitedInt/Product-Details

Comment: You haven't implemented interface `INotifyPropertyChanged ` for `ProductDetail` and called `OnPropertyChanged` for your properties in class `ProductDetail` . Please refer to my answer that I first shared.

Comment: I updated the code to the changes that you provided to me https://github.com/SystemsUnlimitedInt/Product-Details

Comment: I find that you haven't implemented interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`  for `ProductDetail` and called `OnPropertyChanged` for your properties you want to change(e.g.`Quantity`,`QuantityOld `) in class `ProductDetail` yet. And the `Items ` I used is to simulate the `datasource`, you can remove it. You can just use the `ProductDetails` instead.

Comment: And you need to implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` in class `ProductDetail`, not `ProductDetails.xaml`.

Comment: Hi I tried everything i could it still wouldnt work i think the last test i did it showed a blank space at the bottom of the page like i blank list. would you be able to give me a completely new quantity count even if it doesnt pull from mysql i just need a quantity count that works with mvvm, i can do a normal quantity count on a normal page the problem comes in with mvvm

Comment: If you implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your model and add `SetProperty` method for the property,then the UI will refresh itself once changing the value of the property on your viewmodel. Please check class `ProductDetail.cs` on my answer.

Comment: I implemented all the code you provided me with exactly how you gave it but unfortunately nothing worked

Comment: Could you please post the latest code of your app so that I can help your better?

Comment: My latest code is on the github link

Comment: From the github link you shared above,I found you didn't implement the code I advised. Please check code: [ProductDetail.cs](https://github.com/SystemsUnlimitedInt/Product-Details/blob/main/ProductDetail.cs).

Comment: And you don't need to add these properties of `ProductDetails.cs`  to [ProductDetails.xaml.cs](https://github.com/SystemsUnlimitedInt/Product-Details/blob/main/ProductDetails.xaml.cs).

Comment: You haven't implemented  interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your  item `ProductDetail.cs` and added `SetProperty` method for the properties of it.

Comment: You should have mixed Class `ProductDetail.cs`  with `ProductDetails.xaml.cs`.

Comment: Sorry i didnt update the github link

Comment: Hi @Jessie Zhang -MSFT I got the solution to the problem i was facing finally. i added the INotifyPropertyChanged to my ProductDetail as well as a few minor changes on my ProductDetailsViewModel thank you for all your help.